# Error: Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently working on an angularJS app that needs to have a translation functionality, 
So I've checked the Angular-translate library and did everything that's in the example.

However when I run my code I get the following error:

> Error: Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter

I've included my code in the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qYqw8/1/ 
I loaded the angular-translate javascript file before calling the code in the fiddle (which is in portal.js)
this is the order in which I load my files:

```
<script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.10.js"></script>
<script src="js/lib/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="js/portal.js"></script>
```

If anyone can help me out it's highly appreciated,
In case you wondered and since my fiddle is a bit messed up, I did bootstrap my app

```
<html lang="nl" ng-app="portal">
```

thx,

J.

Answer (score 4):

Your fiddle is a bit messed up (for example you don't bootstrap the app and some other deps are missing). But in order to use angular-translate, you need to declare it a dependency in your controller:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $translate) {
  // do some stuff
});
```

Comment: Hi, thx for looking into it, I do however bootstrap my app (I edited the question)

Comment: Also it is no requisite to add $translate to a controller if you want to do it with a filter:
https://github.com/PascalPrecht/angular-translate/blob/master/docs/content/guide/04_using-translate-filter.ngdoc

Comment: Ok then they changed that because for it never worked without the dependency.