# Why Cordova is showing Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating an where I need to translate text in multi language for this I am using 'angular-translate' library while following tutorial. I have done all the necessary setup  things as mentioned in the tutorial but i am getting 'unknown translateFilterProvider' error. I have tried other links over StackOverFlow but those did not work for me as mentioned URL 
[Angular-translate Unknown provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330796/angular-translate-unknown-provider)
[Error: Unknown provider: translateFilterProvider <- translateFilter angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971506/error-unknown-provider-translatefilterprovider-translatefilter-angularjs)

I am new to angular and I have no idea what I am missing. Below is the code I am using
This is my index.html file which has sequence of js file including.

```
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/angulalr-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="service/NetworkManager.js"></script>
<script src="js/Constants.js"></script>
```

This is app.js file code that has config method

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'pascalprecht.translate'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        hello_message: "Howdy",
        goodbye_message: "Goodbye"
    });
    $translateProvider.translations('es', {
        hello_message: "Hola",
        goodbye_message: "Adios"
    });
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage("en");
    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage("en");
});
```

This is my controller where I am injecting my '$translate' as a dependency

```
angular.module('starter', [])
.controller('loginController', function($translate, $scope, constants,            WebserviceCall) {
```

})

and this is the code on index.html where I am using translate as binding expression

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">  
<h1>{{"hello_message" | translate}}</h1>
<h2>{{"goodbye_message" | translate}}</h2>
</div>
```

Any help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to have dependency in the controller again, Change as

```
angular.module('starter')
.controller('loginController', function($translate, $scope, constants,webserviceCall) {
}
```

Comment: I changed my code as you mentioned that error is gone but one more error has occurred as mentioned below 
'no sanitization strategy has been configured' to overcome this I included below line  in my .config method
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');

the error is gone now but nothing is translated

Comment: @AbdulWaheed you need to check other parts of code then, the solution for your question is this anyway

Comment: Well, this is accepted answer the original issue was of dependency as you pointed out... thanks for this.

Comment: one more question, if i am removing [] as you mentioned then $scope is not working on html binding expressions. Why is that so? I mean if I attach any property to $scope and try to access that on html page nothing is show against that property.